# Copy database between two PostgreSQL servers

Tags: database, postgresql, copy

Is there some tool to copy database from one PostgreSQL to other on the fly **NOT INVOLVING BACKUPS/RESTORES**? The tool which automatically keeps database structure on slave server in sync with master server. Probably the tool with differential mode looking at records' primary keys.

I could use replication, but the problem is that it ties two servers in a permanent manner, and I do not need a continuous replication. I need to start it manually. It should terminate when finishes.

I had started to write my own .NET tool using reflection etc, but thought that may be somebody has already written such a tool.

Answer (score 2):

Replication is the term you are looking for.

There are many variations on how to do this. Start by reading the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/high-availability.html) and then google a little.

If the whole-system replication built-in to recent versions of PostgreSQL isn't to your taste then try searching for "slony" or "pg-pool" or "bucardo" (among others).

Comment: Is the replication possible on Herkou?

Comment: Then the problem is that your question isn't accurate and neither will any answers be. Sit down and think exactly what you want to achieve and try posting another question. Make sure you are clear about what you want copied, what you will be changing and what should happen if something has been changed in both databases between updates.